# How to build or condition on datasorce in the code?

Tags: axapta, x++

I have two tables. Lets call them Table1 and Table2. I need to create in the code query like.

```
Select * from Table1 
    exists join Table2 where 
    Table1.Key == Table2.Key &&
    (Table1.A == '1' || Table2.C == '2')
```

So to transfer to code I tried:

```
Query                   q;
QueryBuildDataSource    qbd;
QueryBuildDataSource    ofQbds;
QueryBuildRange         qbr;
str range;
Table1 test;    
QueryRun                    qr;

q = new Query();
qbd = q.addDataSource(tableNum(Table1));
qbd .name('Table1');
ofQbds = qbd.addDataSource(tableNum(Table2));
ofQbds.name('Table2');
ofQbds.addLink(fieldNum(Table1, Key), fieldNum(Table2, Key));

ofQbds.joinMode(JoinMode::InnerJoin);
range = strFmt('%1.%2 == %3 OR %4.%5 == %6', qbd.name(), 'A', '1', 
ofQbds.name(), 'C', '5');
info(range);    
ofQbds.addRange(fieldName2id(tableNum(Table1 ), 'A')).value(range);
qr = new QueryRun(q);
while (qr.next())
{
    test = qr.get(test.TableId);
    info(test.A + ','+test.Key);
}
info('done');
```

But the or condition does not work properly.
For example If I have values

```
Table1
A,Key
1,1
2,2
3,3

Table2
C,Key
2,2
```

I would expect 2 results from Table1

```
1,1
2,2
```

but I get only the first one

```
Message 
Table1.A == 1 OR Table2.C == 2
2,2
done
```

I tried different joinModes and switching || and OR but nothing I tried yet works.

What I need to change to be able to have or condition in the code?

Comment: What version of AX are you using?

Comment: I tried it in Ax2012 and D365

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing this line:

```
range = strFmt('%1.%2 == %3 OR %4.%5 == %6', qbd.name(), 'A', '1', ofQbds.name(), 'C', '5');
```

to

```
range = strFmt('((%1.%2 == %3) || (%4.%5 == %6))', qbd.name(), 'A', '1', ofQbds.name(), 'C', '5');
```

Don't use sql "or", instead use the x++ "||"

Edit: see http://www.axaptapedia.com/Expressions_in_query_ranges for more information.

Edit 2: This code executes for me in the desired fashion. I would recommend using the most up to date compile-time functions such as `tableNum()` and `fieldNum()` etc.

```
    Query                   q;
    QueryBuildDataSource    qbd;
    QueryBuildDataSource    ofQbds;
    QueryBuildRange         qbr;
    str range;
    QueryRun                qr;
    CustTable custTable;
    CustGroup custGroup;

    q = new Query();
    qbd = q.addDataSource(tableNum(CustTable));
    ofQbds = qbd.addDataSource(tableNum(CustGroup));
    ofQbds.addLink(fieldNum(CustTable, CustGroup), fieldNum(CustGroup, CustGroup));
    ofQbds.joinMode(JoinMode::InnerJoin);

    range = strFmt('((%1.%2 == %3) || (%4.%5 == %6))',
        tableStr(CustTable), 
        fieldStr(CustTable, AccountNum), 
        '000001', 
        tableStr(CustGroup), 
        fieldStr(CustGroup, CustGroup), 
        'UAC');

    info(range);
    ofQbds.addRange(fieldNum(CustTable, AccountNum)).value(range);
    qr = new QueryRun(q);

    while (qr.next())
    {
        custTable = qr.get(tableNum(CustTable));
        info(custTable.AccountNum + ',' +custTable.CustGroup);
    }
```

Comment: Use more brackets. I know it sounds silly but often the kernel black box that converts it into SQL needs more brackets to understand the scenario. I will edit in a new proposed code sample in the answer.